# Reversing a number (C++)

Tags: c++, c++14

I am brand new to C++, and am trying to make a simple program to determine if a user-entered integer is four digits, and if so, to reverse the order of said digits and print that output.

I have a (mostly) working program, but when I try, one of two things happens:

a) if line 16 is commented out and line 17 is active, then the program prints out an infinite number of reversed numbers and the IDE (in this case, repl.it) crashes; or

b) if line 17 is commented out and line 16 is active, then the program prints out one correct line, but the next line is "Your number is too short...again" (look at code below)

```
#include <iostream>
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  int n, reversedNumber, remainder;
  bool loopControl;
  char userFinalResponse;
  reversedNumber=0;

  cout<<"Input a 4 digit integer and press Return\n"<<endl;
  cin>>n;
  while (loopControl=true){
    //if ((n>9999)||(n<1000))
    if ((n>9999)||((n<1000)&&(n>0)))
    {
      cout<<"Your number is too short or too long. Please try again.\n"<<endl;
      cin>>n;
      loopControl=false;
    } else {
      while(n != 0)
      {
        remainder = n%10;
        reversedNumber=reversedNumber*10+remainder;
        n /= 10;
        loopControl=true;
      }//closing brace for reversal loop
      cout<<"Your reversed number is "<<reversedNumber<<"\n"<<endl;
    }//closing brace for else
  }//closing brace for "while (loopControl>0){"
  return 0;
}//closing brace for "int main() {"
```

Comment: Simply you could use std::to_string() to convert the number to a string, check the length, call reverse and the job is done!

Comment: `while (loopControl=true){` This condition is always true, the loop never terminates. Check your favorite C++ reference for the difference between assignment `=` and equality comparison `==`. All iterations except the first run with `n == 0`, that's why `n>0` check makes a difference.

Comment: Or better yet, use a compiler which warns you if you've used `=` when you probably meant `==`.

Comment: Ensure you compile with a sufficiently high warning level and you get a compilation warning like "warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   while (loopControl=true){". I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang. Not sure what you'd use on MSVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`cpp tutorials`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/operators/) `=` is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator. Because of this your `while` loop will never terminate. You can simply initialize `loopControl` to true, and then set it to false when it's okay to exit:

```
int n, reversedNumber, remainder;
bool loopControl = true;  //Initialize to true
char userFinalResponse;
reversedNumber = 0;

cout << "Input a 4 digit integer and press Return\n" << endl;
cin >> n;
while (loopControl) {
    //if ((n>9999)||(n<1000))
    if ((n>9999) || ((n<1000) && (n>0)))
    {
        cout << "Your number is too short or too long. Please try again.\n" << endl;
        cin >> n;
        loopControl = true;  //need to keep on looping
    }
    else {
        while (n > 0)
        {
            remainder = n % 10;
            reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + remainder;
            n /= 10;
            loopControl = false; //Ok to exit
        }//closing brace for reversal loop
        cout << "Your reversed number is " << reversedNumber << "\n" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
int number = 1874 //or whatever you need
auto str = std::to_string(number);

if (str.length() == 4) {
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

I suggest you to give a look at the `algorithm` header that contains a lot of useful methods that can help you while developing programs.